# Load NSAttributedString from File

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, nsattributedstring

Is there a way to have some sort of rich text in a file, and load the file into an NSAttributedString? I looked into loading a .rtf file into an NSAttributed String:

```
NSString *filePathFooter = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:kFooterFileName ofType:@"rtf"];

NSError *error = nil;
NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithFileURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePathFooter]
                                                                 options:nil
                                                      documentAttributes:NULL
                                                                   error:&error];
```

But this leaves me with:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=258 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 258.)"
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Use `URLForResource` instead, and pass the resulting URL like so:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:kFooterFileName withExtension:@"rtf"];

NSError *error = nil;
NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithFileURL:url
                                                                 options:nil
                                                      documentAttributes:NULL
                                                                   error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSCocoaErrorDomain` error code 258 is `NSFileReadInvalidFileNameError`, so it looks like it can't find the file you're passing.